# Allow function/loop to run while msgbox is open VBA

Tags: vba, msgbox

I'm finishing up a program and want to do something *fancy* for the "about" tab. I'm a huge fan of easter-eggs and such, and wanted to do something cool. My idea was when the button is pressed, run a function to do color-tiles with the cells while a msgbox pop says "hey thanks for using my program" or something like that, then the function ends as soon as msgbox "ok" has been clicked. Is there any easy way to do this? It's not super important but it would be really useful for future applications as well.

here is kinda what I want:

```
do while msgbox <> ok
'something amazing I guess
next
```

I couldn't find anything remotely similar; that being said I might not be asking the right question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a custom userform and show it using the non-modal option.

Comment: @TimWilliams, if I understand those, it won't work. I need the function to be infinite until "ok" is pressed. My understanding was that non-modal userforms terminated upon the end of a time/task rather than the form being closed itself.

Comment: Non-modals stay open until you close them. You would launch the form before going into the loop, then have a button on the form which terminates the loop (by setting a Global flag or a property on the form which is checked from within your loop) - when your loop detects the "OK" it exits.  You might have to use DoEvents to allow the form to respond to the OK button, depending on what type of loop you plan to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you could do a Non-Modal form that opens on a Click Event, with something like:

```
Do While msgbox("Hey thanks for using my Kick-ass," & Vbcrlf & _
" better then you ever thought possible program",vbokonly,"Title of Program here") <> vbok

'tell you form do colour tiles and any form of magic you want here

next
```

Vbok, is what is returned by the Msgbox.